# Is there an operator in typescript that replaces ternary operator with same condition and if value

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript I often use the ternary operator to check if a variable is undefined. If it isn't I would like to return that variable, while if it is I would like to return a default value:

```
var x: string = y ? y : "default"
```

This becomes very tedious and space consuming when using long expressions:

```
(kids as Array<React.ReactNode>) ? (kids as Array<React.ReactNode>) : kidsDefaultValue
```

Is there a way to shorten this without having to repeat value `y` as in the first example?

Comment: Just use plain js: `y || "default"`

Comment: It depends on the type. I prefer `y ?? "default"` see [MDN Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). Somethimes you want to replace only `null`/`undefines`  because `""`, `0`, `false` might be valid values.